# Error in R: Foreach function : "plot.new has not been called yet"

Tags: r, plot, foreach, doparallel

I am trying to develop an R function to highlight multi-polygons in parallel using foreach command:

```
  library(deldir); library(plyr); library(rgdal);
  library(doParallel);library(foreach); 

  #Detecting the number of cores available
  num_cores <- detectCores() - 1
  clust <- makeCluster(num_cores, type = "PSOCK")
  registerDoParallel(clust)

  Shape <- readOGR(dsn = ".\\Data\\greatlakes_subbasins",
                   layer = "greatlakes_subbasins")

  idpoly <- lapply(Shape@polygons , slot , "ID")
  plot(Shape, axes=T, asp=1)

  foreach(j = 1 : iter(idpoly)$length, .packages = c('deldir','plyr','rgdal')
  ) %dopar% {

      #print(j)
      coord <- Shape@polygons[[j]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords         
      coord <- coord[-1,] 

      points(coord,col="orange",pch=20, cex=2)
      box()

  }
  stopCluster(clust)
```

However, I get the error:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "plot.new has not been called yet"
```

I have gone through similar issues discussed in other forums and stack overflow, and it seems to indicate that this probably is an issue with plot() function being called outside the foreach and the points() executes without the access to plot().

Can anyone let me know if I am going in the right direction? Also, if there is any suggestion to get around this.

Link to the [shapefile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DLp2Z50tvWG-9e-P8M3m0JC6jtq_IoYg/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Basically, `plot` is run in your main R session while `points` are run in other sessions (because of parallelism).

Comment: Yes. That is what I realized as well, however, is there a way that I plot the main plot once and iteratively draw each polygon? I tried to move the plot within the 'foreach' but it returns NULL and does not plot any of the polygon points nor the main plot.

Comment: I would return only the data of the plots, and then plot them in the main session.

Comment: Yes. However, When I do get the results and plot it in the main session, I cannot return to the 'foreach' session again in case I want to add more functionalty after plotting the points.I want to calculate delaunay triangulations for each of the ploygons that are identified. Any suggestions to cater to that ?

Comment: Thank you @F. Prive. I managed to follow what you suggested and get the results!